# Why can an instance passed into a method with the ref keyword remain unchanged after creating a new object?

Tags: c#, object, methods, reference, instance

I've come across this tricky issue. See the following code:

```
public class Foo
    public int A { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Foo foo1 = new Foo();
    Foo foo2 = new Foo();

    ChangeObject1(foo1);
    ChangeObject2(ref foo2);

    Console.WriteLine("Foo1 = " + foo1.A);
    Console.WriteLine("Foo2 = " + foo2.A);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void ChangeObject1(Foo foo)
{
    foo.A += 1;
    foo = new Foo();
}

static void ChangeObject2(ref Foo foo)
{
    foo.A += 1;
    foo = new Foo();
}
```

After some testing, foo1.A is equal to 1, and foo2.A is still equal to 0. To my understanding, this is because the second method has the instance passed in by reference rather than value. This changes the content of the instance, so when a new object is created and assigned in the method, the value is no longer defined.

But thinking about it confuses me as I feel that there should be similar effects in the first method, even if it's passed by value because the content of the instance is still changed outside of the method.

Anyone know whats actually going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that you're using c# or java.  either way, the concept remains the same

when you declare your foo variables

```
Foo foo1 = new Foo()
```

you're declaring what is called a reference type.  (all objects that represent classes are reference types)

so, the value stored in `foo1` isn't really a `Foo`, but it's a value that holds the memory address of that `Foo`.

when you call

```
    static void ChangeObject1(Foo foo)
    {
        foo.A += 1;
        foo = new Foo();
    }
```

you're passing a copy of that reference.  Therefore, when you do `foo.A += 1`, you're changing the member value of the object that you've just passed in.

when you do `foo = new Foo();`  you're only changing the copy of the reference, but not the original object reference itself.

now, when you call

```
    static void ChangeObject2(ref Foo foo)
    {
        foo.A += 1;
        foo = new Foo();
    }
```

you're not passing a copy of the address of your `Foo` but you're passing the address of the address of your `Foo`.

you can think of it as though you're passing the original `Foo` address itself.

So when you call `foo = new Foo()`, it doesn't matter what you did to foo before that.  You've just over-written your address with the address of a brand new `Foo` object.

if you change your method to look like the following

```
    static void ChangeObject2(ref Foo foo)
    {
        foo.A += 1;
    }
```

then you should notice the change

[Here's a page that explains reference types](http://www.roseindia.net/java/master-java/Reference-Data-Types.shtml)  It's in java, but the same principles apply to c# too

Comment: Apologies; the language is in C#. And I see! I just figured that if code in the first method could change a member variable of the original instance even though it is a copy (like you said, an address is passed in), then the assignment of a new instance would also stand, meaning the object outside of the method is still reinialized. How come the member isn't changed only for the copy in the method?

Comment: @oppositeofyou  the member is changed, BUT you're no longer passing in a copy of the address, you're passing in the address itself*, so when you type `foo = new Foo();`  you're over-writing that address.   *(technically you're passing an address to the address)

Comment: "all user-defined objects are reference types" I disagree, struct are not ref types they are value types

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps if you think about it in terms of a value type instead of a reference type it would help. Take the first example (number in brackets represents a memory address which holds an integer value).

**Passing by Value**

```
[0001] -> 5;
```

When you pass by value, the value 5 is copied to a new memory address

```
[0002] -> 5;    
[0002] -> 10;    // changes the value of a new reference
```

Changing the value of [0002] will not affect [0001].

---

**Passing by Reference**

```
[0001] -> 5;
```

On the other hand if you pass the address itself (passing with the ref keyword)

```
[0001] -> 5;    
[0001] -> 10;    // changes the value of the original reference
```

You can now change the value the reference is holding.

---

Reference types instead of holding an integer hold an address to an object. So it stands that if you pass by reference you are passing the 'container' (ie pointer/reference) which holds the value. You can then change what the container holds. If you pass by value, you are taking the value out of the container and passing it, then the original container is out of the picture.

Comment: This answer is even more confusing, because it uses value types (integers), while the question uses reference types.

Comment: I clearly state why the example uses value types. It is easier to see what is happening and is the exact same concept when passing with the ref keyword. Which sounds more confusing, A container that holds a value, or a container that holds a container that holds a value? Yet the concept of passing a container, or the value it holds remains the same. Feel free to replace the integers with long hexadecimal memory addresses if that makes it easier for you to understand, it's irrelevant to the point.